# Time & date chart in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, charts

I would  like to make a visual representation of my arrival and departure times at the office.

This means I need to chart timestamp and date.
I tried several things in Excel, different charts, but to no avail. 
A chart with only the date and random numbers give a perfect chart as result, but changing the random numbers by time, with time format gives a chart with dates starting from 1900 until 2036, and the time is represented by 1/2/3/4/5 with series 1 and series 2.

I can't imagine it is this difficult to chart time and date in Excel, or am I missing the point?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPXLP.jpg)

Any advise is welcome, and let it be known, I'm not a geek, nor Office expert.

Comment: For a line chart, change your Legend Entries (Series) to your times, and change your Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels to your dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a real PITA, because of foibles in the way Excel creates graphs, I suppose.  Here's how I got it done, but if anyone knows an easier way, please don't hesitate to post your solution.

First, check the formatting of your data table.  In the picture below, Column A is formatted as Date (*3/14/01), Columns B and C are formatted as Time(1:30 PM), and Columns D and E are formatted as Number (w/4 decimal places):

[image]

When formatted as a number, the times become a decimal representing the fraction of a day, e.g. 12:00 PM would display as 0.5000.  Make sure your times change to decimals when formatted as a number.  If that doesn't happen, they may have been entered as text.

Next, create a **blank** scatter or line graph:  With no data selected, choose Scatter or Line from the Graph menu.  Then use the Graph > Source Data... menu to add the first series.  Select the appropriate data ranges (B3 as Name, A4:A16 as X-values, and B4:B16 as Y-values) in the resulting dialog box.  You should get something like this:

[image]

Finally, use the Graph>Source Data... menu again to add the second series:

[image]

I hope this works for you.  Post a comment back here if you run into problems.  Good luck.

Comment: You can also manipulate a date/time entry (e.g. '17 Jan 2017 05:03" to only take the fractional part, which gives the same 'decimal number' as above. The crux of this is understanding how Excel stores dates and times - and then using this to your advantage.